# Centos 8 Kickstart installation ignoring custom partioning

Tags: kickstart, centos8

I am installing Centos 8 on a hard drive that already has a Centos 7 installation.  I created a kickstart file by performing the installation manually.  When I try to use the kickstart file it fails to pick up the custom partitioning information and halts, asking me to supply the destination for the install.

The relevant section of the kickstart file is:

```
# Disk partitioning information
part /boot --fstype="ext4" --ondisk=sda --size=95367
part /boot/efi --fstype="efi" --ondisk=sda --size=976 --fsoptions="umask=0077,shortname=winnt"
part pv.476 --fstype="lvmpv" --ondisk=sda --size=1342792
part pv.31 --fstype="lvmpv" --noformat
volgroup cl00 --pesize=4096 pv.476
volgroup centos_gracedev3 --noformat --useexisting
logvol /home --fstype="xfs" --size=381469 --name=home --vgname=cl00
logvol swap --fstype="swap" --size=7629 --name=swap --vgname=cl00
logvol /var --fstype="xfs" --size=476837 --name=var --vgname=cl00
logvol / --fstype="xfs" --size=476837 --name=root --vgname=cl00
logvol swap --fstype="swap" --noformat --useexisting --name=swap --vgname=centos_gracedev3
```

Comment: What is already on the hard drive?

Comment: There are three partitions on the drive: 1) An EFI partition, 2) a /boot partition, and 3) an lvm, which contains three partitons for a Centos 7 installation.  The logical volumes within the lvm partition are root, swap and home for Centos 7.  The installation works fine, when I provide the  destination partitions manually.